# How do i swap objects properties Swift

Tags: swift, copy, swap

Hi I'm trying to make a chess game and I'm currently trying to build a function where given two chess squares, swap the chesspieces on the squares.  Each square is a class that has an optional ChessPiece object.  My current problem is that when I move one chesspiece to the other squares chesspiece property, both chesspieces end up pointing to the same object since they then referring to the same square property.

```
 private func swapSquares(square1: Square, square2: Square) {

    if square1.chessPiece == nil && square2.chessPiece == nil {
        return
    }

    var square1ChessPiece: ChessPiece?
    var square2ChessPiece: ChessPiece?

    if let square1piece = square1.chessPiece {
        square1ChessPiece = square1piece
    }

    if let square2piece = square2.chessPiece {
        square2ChessPiece = square2piece
    }

    if let square1piece = square1ChessPiece {
        square1piece.frame = square2.frame
        square1piece.square = square2
        square2.chessPiece = square1piece    // after this, square1ChessPiece and Square2Chess become the same
    }
    if let square2piece = square2ChessPiece {
        square2piece.frame = square1.frame
        square2piece.square = square1
        square1.chessPiece = square2piece
    }
}
```

Do I need to go make a deep copy of both chesspieces so I can easily swap positions?  Otherwise it seems like the commented line will just have both chesspiece objects point to the same location in memory.

Comment: The problem is that both square and chesspiece are classes so they are passed by reference.  The variable storing it will also have the changes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use swap method and declare both of your method parameters adding the keyword inout to them:

```
struct ChessPiece {
    let piece: String
}
struct Square {
    let row: Int
    let col: Int
    var chessPiece: ChessPiece?
}
```

---

```
private func swapSquaresPieces(square1: inout Square, square2: inout Square) {
    swap(&square1.chessPiece, &square2.chessPiece)
}
```

---

```
var square1 = Square(row: 1, col: 1, chessPiece: ChessPiece(piece: "queen"))
var square2 = Square(row: 2, col: 2, chessPiece: ChessPiece(piece: "king"))

swapSquaresPieces(square1: &square1, square2: &square2)

print(square1)
print(square2)
```

This will print

> Square(row: 1, col: 1, chessPiece: Optional(ChessPiece(piece: "king")))
>
> Square(row: 2, col: 2, chessPiece:
>   Optional(ChessPiece(piece: "queen")))